# Prevent loading components with default values in React useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, pagination

I am working with offset pagination in typescript react.

I have two states that contain `pageNumber` and `offset`. The default page is set to `1` and the default offset is set to `0` as you can see below.

**`useState` Hook**

```
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [calculatedOffset, setCalculatedOffset] = useState(0);
```

On load, the component fetches `pageNumber` and `calculatedOffset` from the `localStorage` and updates the defaults of the useState values.

**`useEffect` Hook**

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      const integerPage = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("currentPage") || "1");
      setCurrentPage(integerPage);

      const integerOffset = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("calculatedOffset") || "0");
      setCalculatedOffset(integerOffset);
    }
  }, []);
```

**THE PROBLEM:**

The problem I am facing is that whenever the component loads, it loads up with the values of the default state, i.e. `pageNumber: 1, calculatedOffset: 0` for half a second then changes it to the updated state that was which was updated when the `useEffect` hook ran. So on every load, the component flashes the data of the default state before ending up from the updated state fetched from localStorage.

Is there a way I can make it where the component only loads when the states have ended up on their final values and prevent the old states flashing for half a second behaviour every time the component loads?

Answer (score 1):

`useEffect` runs when the component has been rendered fully. So before that happens, `useState` is already used to initialise the variables according to which your components are initially rendered.

To prevent the initial render according to the initialised value from `useState`, set both to `null` in `useState` and in the component, render the elements conditionally:

```js
{!currentPage || element}
```

or

```js
{currentPage && element}
```

Comment: I did not understand what you meant by render elements conditionally with the examples you showed. And what values should I change to null including the useState default values. Can you explain it a bit more, please?

Comment: It means that you are rendering elements based on a condition (if it is true or false). In this case !null will give you true so when we use `||` and the first one is true, it won't check (in this case, render) the second term. Similarly for `&&` where it will not check the second term if the first one is false (null) and it will render the element if the first one is true.

Comment: You should look up conditional rendering. It is a very important part of React (at least) (and in this manner using bitwise operators). It will be needed in many cases.